# UUI not showing in boot options

Tags: boot, 18.04, live-usb, reinstall

i want to reinstall ubuntu from a bootable USB, when i go into the startup menu on my hp elitebook it only shows me the options to boot into ubuntu recovery mode or simple ubuntu. I want it to boot from the USB drive but its not listed in the menu

Comment: On many of my machines, I have to press a key to get a USB/thumb-drive to boot (including some HP).  The key varies on make/model  (I think it's F9 on most HP desktops, laptops (particularly consumer grade devices) tend to vary far more than enterprise geared desktops)

Comment: @karel No this doesn't help. My problem is that i don't have any option on screen that boots the laptop from USB. It doesn't show anything except the recovery mode.

Comment: @guiverc i have to press the Esc key on my hp laptop to enter into startup menu. i tried pressing F10-i read it somewhere that this would work but it doesn't. Should i press F9 instead of Esc key?

Comment: There is no set standard; F9 works on most my HP desktops. I think it's F12 on the dell desktop I'm currently using, however particularly for laptops it seems to vary (enterprise or business geared high-end laptops more consistent, consumer grade or sleek netbooks are less consistent in my experience. The *elitebook* name seems to imply to me a *netbook* class, often made by other companies and just have HP' added to it,  but I don't know your device/model, so don't know what key it'll be for you